# Netbeans insert new line at end of file c/c++

Tags: c++, netbeans

When I use nebeans formatter it is removing new line from end of file

while using gcc I am getting warning

```
warning: no newline at end of file
```

How can I force netbeans to insert new line at end of file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Netbeans supports the concept of code templates - you'll find the option to modify the templates under "Tools>Templates". Edit the C++ code templates, and insert a new line at the end of the templates. Then when you select to create a new C++ file, it will use the template - which will contain the new line you require.

EDIT: Ahh - just read your question properly!!! DOH. I'm surprised the formatting removes a line, as it doesn't in my selected style (I use the "NetBeans" style), may be try one of the other ones - I can't see the option to remove blank lines in the list of options... On a side note, I'm running 7.0, so don't know if it's different in yours. The above bit about templates still stands though to create a new file with a new line.

Comment: sorry new line was got removed by template only . after editing the template I am not getting that issue.